# como contar parte de contenido de un arraylist

Tags: java

lo que quiero es contar la cantidad de trabajadores que tienen un tipo determinado de char
 como por ejemplo los que son del tipo 'P' y los que son del tipo 'R'

```
 List<Trabajador> trabajadores = new ArrayList<Trabajador>();

        trabajadores.add(new Trabajador("t0001","37546352", "Carlos", "Diaz", "Analista Programador", 26, 3000.0, 'P'));
        trabajadores.add(new Trabajador("t0002","37553452", "Oscar ", "Rodriguez", "Contador", 22, 2500.0, 'P'));
        trabajadores.add(new Trabajador("t0003","37685672", "Cesar", "Carmelo", "Gerente", 40, 1500.0, 'P'));
        trabajadores.add(new Trabajador("t0004","38956252", "Josue", "Cardenaz", "Practicante", 35, 850.0, 'R'));
        trabajadores.add(new Trabajador("t0005","94523442", "Richard", "Acosta", "Tecnico", 36, 1800.0, 'R'));   


        em.setTrabajadores(trabajadores);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deseas contar elementos de tu [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) por un determinado atributo de tu clase `Trabajador` a partir de Java8 podrías usar [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) haciendo uso de [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) de la clase [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) para agruparlos por atributo.
y un [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) para almacenar `clave` y `valor`

```
/* Tomando en cuenta que tu valor a comparar es un Character, long es
 el valor devuelto por counting , getValue será su getter del atributo char*/ 
Map<Character, Long> t=  
trabajadores.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(Trabajador::getValue, Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(t);
```

O Un método sencillo recorriendo la `Lista` y comparando cada uno de ellos

```
int Counting(List<Trabajador> lista,char a)
{
    int count=0;
    for (Trabajador pe: lista) {
        if(String.valueOf(pe.getValue()).toLowerCase().
           equals(String.valueOf(a).toLowerCase()))
            count+=1;
    }
    return count;
}
System.out.println(Counting(trabajadores, 'A'));
```